# Delete of array of pointer: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

I have a code in which I need to allocate a pointer to an array of pointers, but when I want to be safely deleted it, debugger gives me error.

[image]

I know I should not use a pointer array of pointers but the vector class, but I had to do it in this way.
I have two classes: A e B. In B.h I have this:

```
private: A **aObject;
```

In B.cpp I make this:

```
aObject = new A*[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    aObject[i] = new A();
}
```

When I want to deleted it, I do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    delete [i]aObject; // <----error debuger
}
delete []aObject;
```

I have read many threads that talking about that and it seems that the method I use is correct. Debuger return an error at line 62 `delete [i]aObject;`.
So, have you any idea for fix it?
Moreover, it return error when `i` is 1. Private members of A object (`aObject`) are `CXX0030`.
Looks like I'm addressing an area of memory out of my address space, `aObject` is a null pointer, so the debugging returns the error on heap.
Thanks guys.

**EDIT:**
Okei, with `delete aObject[i]` I no longer have this error, but I have another error: `0xc0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0094e368`. Now return error when `i` is 0. Error always at line 62. Private members of `aObject` are `CXX0017` and the value of `aObject` is `0x0094e368`.

**EDIT 2:**
I have not defined any destructor for `A`, only the default one, but I do not recall it anywhere.

```
A::~A(void){}
```

**EDIT 3:**
`B.h`, aka `bci.h` (sorry for my mistake)

```
#pragma once

#include "thinkgear.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "eeg.h"
#include <string>

class bci {

public:

    bci(float timeAcquisition);
    ~bci(void);

    // FUNZIONI BCI //
    // -> Connessione e setting della bci <- //
    void autoInit(void);
    int getDriverVersion(void);
    void setNumPortCom(void);
    void setNumPortCom(int portNumber);
    void getConnectionId(void);
    void connect(void); //Stablisce una connessione alla bci e setta connectionId
    void setStreamLog(const char *filename);
    void setStreamLog(void);
    void setDataLog(const char *filename);
    void setDataLog(void);
    void enableLowPassFilter(void);
    void disableLowPassFilter(void);
    void enableBlinkDetection(void); //Abilita il blink detection
    void disableBlinkDetection(void); //Disabilit il blink detection
    void disconnected(void); //Libera la connessione con la bci

    // -> Lettura e storing EEG <- //
    void readAllEEGValues(void);
    void storeAllEEGValues(void);
    void readStoreAllEEGValues(void);

    // -> Lettura e storing EEG (escluso segnale RAW) <- // poor signal e blink detectection inclusi
    void readEEGValues(void); //Legge i dati dalla bci e aggiorna la variabili
    void storeEEGValues(void);
    void readStoreEEGValues(void);

    // -> Lettura e storing segnale RAW <- //
    void readEEGRawValue(void);
    void storeEEGRawValues(void);
    void readStoreEEGRawValues(void);

    // -> Lettura e storing eSense Meter (attention e meditation) <- // poor signal e blink detectection inclusi
    void readESenseValues(void);
    void storeESenseValues(void);
    void readStoreESenseValues(void);

    // METODI GETTER E SETTER //
    // -> Getter e Setter per i dati estratti <- //
    time_t getTimestamp(int i);
    float getLevelAttention(int i); //Restituisce il livello attuale di attenzione
    float getLevelMeditation(int i); //Restituisce il livello attuale di meditazione
    float getLevelRaw(int i);
    float getLevelDelta(int i);
    float getLevelTheta(int i);
    float getLevelAlpha1(int i);
    float getLevelAlpha2(int i);
    float getLevelBeta1(int i);
    float getLevelBeta2(int i);
    float getLevelGamma1(int i);
    float getLevelGamma2(int i);
    float getBlinkStrengthDetection(int i); //Restitisce il livello attuale del blink detection (o dell'ultimo blink)
    time_t* getTimestamp(void);
    float* getLevelAttention(void); //Restituisce il livello attuale di attenzione
    float* getLevelMeditation(void); //Restituisce il livello attuale di meditazione
    float* getLevelRaw(void);
    float* getLevelDelta(void);
    float* getLevelTheta(void);
    float* getLevelAlpha1(void);
    float* getLevelAlpha2(void);
    float* getLevelBeta1(void);
    float* getLevelBeta2(void);
    float* getLevelGamma1(void);
    float* getLevelGamma2(void);
    float* getBlinkStrengthDetection(void); //Restitisce il livello attuale del blink detection (o dell'ultimo blink)
    bool checkBlinkDetection(void); //Controlla se è avvenuto o meno un bink
    // -> Getter e Setter per gli errori <- //
    int getIdConnection(void);
    int getErrorStreamLog(void);
    int getErrorDataLog(void);
    int getErrorLowPassFilter(void);
    int getErrorBlinkDetection(void);
    int getErrorConnect(void);
    int getPacketsRead(void);
    int getPacketsAnalize(void);

    // LETTURA ERRORI //
    // -> Interpretato gli errori ricevuti <- //
    std::string getStringErrorConnectionId(void);
    std::string getStringErrorStreamLog(void);
    std::string getStringErrorDataLog(void);
    std::string getStringErrorLowPassFilter(void);
    std::string getStringErrorBlinkDetection(void);
    std::string getStringErrorConnect(void);
    /*std::string getStringPacketsRead(void);
    std::string getStringPacketsAnalize(void);*/

    // -> Printing di valori estratti e di variabili utili <- //
    void printBciInfo(void); //Stampa alcune informazioni utili della classe
    void printValues(void);
    void printDataValues(void);
    void printESenseValues(void);

    // -> Metodo setter e getter per timeAcquisition <- //
    // * Numero di campionamenti da fare, o numero di secondi di running della bci * //
    void setTimeAcquisition(int time);
    int getTimeAcquisition(void);

    // -> Salva il segnale EEG <- //
    // * num viene utilizzato nel seguente  modo: se num=0, stampa tutti tranne raw; num=1, stampa solo il raw; num=2, stampa tutto.
    void saveToCsv(const char *filename, int num);
    void saveToCsv(int num);

    // -> Altro <- //
    float* convertRawToVoltage(void); //Converte la matrice data che contiene tutti i segnali raw ai rispetti valori in Volt.
    float convertRawToVoltage(float rawValue); //Converte il valore raw e ritorna il rispettivo valore in Volt.

    // -> Prova <- //
    //eeg** 

    // -> Non implementata <- //
    //void cleanDataFile(void);

    /*void cleanCSVFile(const char *filename);
    std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems);
    std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim);*/

private:

    int connectionId; //Id della connessione alla bci. 0 ok, -2 no free memory to allocate connection, -1 to many connection without TG_FreeConnection()
    int dllVersion;
    int numPortCom;

    time_t *timer;
    float *attention; //Livello di attenzione attuale
    float *blinkStrength; //Livello di blink attuale
    bool blink; //E' a 'true' se si è verificato un blink, 'false' altrimenti,
    float *meditation; //Livello di meditazione attuale
    float *poorSignal; //Qualità del segnale ricevuto
    float *raw;
    float *delta;
    float *theta;
    float *alpha1;
    float *alpha2;
    float *beta1;
    float *beta2;
    float *gamma1;
    float *gamma2;

    int errorStreamLog; //-1 invalid id connection, -2 error with file, 0 success
    int errorDataLog; //-1 invalid id connection, -2 error with file, 0 success
    int errorLowPassFilter; //-1 invalid id connection, -2 rawSamplingRate is not a valid rate, 0 success
    int errorBlinkDetection; //-1 invalid id connection, 0 success
    int errorConnect; //-1 invalid id connection, -2 serialPortName could not be opened, -3 if serialBaudrate is not a valid TG_BAUD_* value, -4 if @c serialDataFormat is not a valid TG_STREAM_* type, 0 success
    int errorReadPackets; //-1 invalid id connection, -2 if there were not even any bytes available to be read, -3 if an I/O error occurs

    int packetsRead; //Handler per la lettura dei dati dalla bci
    int packetsAnalize; //Contatore per il numero totale di pacchetti letti dalla bci

    int timerAcquisition;

    eeg **data;

};
```

**EDIT 4:**
*Maybe I found the problem.*
In the main function I do this:

```
int main(void) {
        ...
    B *bObject=new B(timeAcquisition);
        ...
    bObject->~B();
    delete bObject; //<--- THIS!
}
```

It is possible? Without `delete bObject;` debugger does not return any error.

**EDIT 5:**
So, the **answer is** [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/248aa748.aspx):

> Using the delete operator also causes the class destructor (if there is one) to be called.

Comment: What is this `delete [i]aObject;` ?

Comment: `delete aObject[i];` would make more sense.

Comment: Using RAII would make more sense.

Comment: `delete [i]aObject;` is perfectly valid (although rarely used, and ugly & leetish). I suspect the error is somewhere else (or there is a bug in the compiler's handling of "odd order of index).

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think you're confusing `[i]aObject` with `i[aObject]`.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me the object class that holds the member variable `A** aObject;` does NOT have a proper virtual destructor, copy constructor, or assignment operator, and you're implicitly making at least one copy (shallow), destroying it, and subsequent access to the original is faulting because the copied pointer is no longer valid. Post the *entire* class definition of the class containing `A **aObject;`. Then read [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: By far the most common reason for this diagnostic is heap corruption.  Which is always hard to debug since the corruption occurred well before your program crashes.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yes, of course... Doh!

Comment: @RaymondChen so `delete [i]aObject` is not a valid istruction?

Comment: @lezan The problem is in class "B", not "A".

Comment: @lezan pay attention to WhozCraig's comment, my bet's that you're copying a bci object. Also, careful returning the pointer members.

Comment: Why do you call `MindSet->~B();` before `delete bObject`?

Comment: @Paul: I thought it was correct. With `delete bObject` before `bObject->~B();` I have another error in another istruction `delete []aObject;`

Comment: Destructor is called by `operator delete`, why do you call it manually at all? You should only call destructor manually if you use placement new or you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Paul: In `~B();` I put the delete of `aObject`,                 `for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    delete [i]aObject;
}`
delete []aObject;

Comment: @lezan If you had compiled with warnings enabled, you would have gotten [this warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9z4waxa.aspx) which explains what is happening.

Comment: If you found the solution, then please do not add it to the question but post it as an answer and accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/248aa748.aspx):

> Using the delete operator also causes the class destructor (if there is one) to be called.

```
int main(void) {
        ...
    B *bObject=new B(timeAcquisition);
        ...
    delete bObject;
}
```